# push notification not received by iPad

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apns-sharp

We are running into an issue with push notification. We are sending alerts to iPad app through apple sand box. From our C# console, it connects to APNS (TCP/IP), authenticates SSL and sends notification. But the device didn't receive anything. Certificate(.pem) generated for development environment and we are sending the notification in ByteArray format. Is there a way to validate the device token?(meaning are we targeting the right device). Also how to retrieve the status through enhanced notification format. Any feedback/suggession would be of great help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A couple questions:

1. How are you sending the notification in byte array format?
2. Isn't the Notification just a string formatted as Json?

A couple things you should be doing:

1. Also you can be using the development certificate but in your code you've not set the environment to be sandbox.
2. And most importantly you should be using a .p12 file as your certificate not a .pem file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. We now switched to prodcution server. Refer all the details below, we still have the same issue.

Comment: We are able to connect(tcp), authenticate(ssl) and send notifications to APNS but the notifications are not being dispatched to devices. No errors reported.
Server – gateway.push.apple.com, Port - 2195 
Certificate & key generated using production profile. Console application uses PFX formatted file to make connection 
[PFX file is generated through Openssl commands using the certificate and key] 
Device is enabled to receive notifications. [Setting->Notifications-> Badge/Alert/Sound set to ON] 
Application has been registered for Push notification and installed in the device (iPad)

Comment: We use “apns-sharp“ C# code to send notifications. Notification has 3 components (badge/alert/sound) in string formatted Json.               

Note:
We use EnhancedNotificationFormat to retrieve the status. After sending the notification, the call back routine which gives us the status never gets into a completed status (even after 2 minutes wait interval). We have to dispose the aync call back channel to exit from the wait status.

Your response is highly appreciated. Thank you.